# Shopify Bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, shopify

I'm working on a bootstrap carousel for shopify and well first I'm having a problem with the indicators they are displaying for the correct amount of images. but after the second indicator clicking on the indicator it no longer works

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
  
     
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        {% for image in product.images %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      
            {% else %}
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li> 
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'master' }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ product.title }}" width="100%" />
                </div>
      
      
      {% if count_images > 0 %}
                    {% for image in product.images  offset:1 %} 
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ product.title }}" width="100%" style="min;height: 115px !important;" />
                </div> 
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
     
          
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code. The first is all your subsequent indicators target your second image. 
The second is the featured image will usually be the first image but there's no guarantee so you need to test whether your image is the featured image or not.

Try:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">

    {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}      
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        {% for image in product.images %}

        {% assign activeClass = '' %}
        {% if featured_image.id == image.id %} {% assign activeClass = 'active' %}{% endif %}
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="{{forloop.index0}}" class="{{activeClass}}"></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for image in product.images %}
            {% assign activeClass = '' %}
            {% if featured_image.id == image.id %} {% assign activeClass = 'active' %}{% endif %} 

                <div class="item {{activeClass}}">
                    <img src="{{ image | img_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ product.title }}" style="min-height: 115px !important;" />
                </div> 
        {% endfor %}
    </div>


    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Works better then my current code but the Indicators are still off

Comment: how so? Do you have a sample page?

Comment: it's off by the very last image

Comment: Yes. sorry I was looking at your original code and didn't recall slide-to properly. Sample is fixed.